# A Genetic Introduction to Algebraic Geometry

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I am a big fan of "genetic introductions" in mathematics, i.e. where the ideas are introduced in the order they were developed along with why they were introduced, as opposed to the "definition-theorem-proof" kind of introductions on the line of Bourbaki. 
For Galois Theory, Algebraic Number Theory and Analytic Number Theory, there are Edwards' wonderful books Galois Theory(Springer), Fermat's Last Theorem(Springer) and Riemann's Zeta Function(Dover). I am a big fan of these books, and this style of exposition.

Now I am looking for a similar exposition in Algebriac Geometry. But all the books I know of in that subject area more or less follows the Bourbaki track. Anyone knows about one?

P.S. if you know of this kind of exposition in other streams of mathematics, please let me to know.

Comment: Do you mean something like Dieudonné's article "The historical development of algebraic geometry"?

Comment: this seems relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174435/algebraic-geometry-text-recommendation?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The book "Algebraic Geometry " by Shafarevich is a good book which is written with lot of motivations.  It is certainly not written in the Bourbaki style.

Answer (score 0):

Fulton's "Algebraic curves" is a good introductory book that requires some knowledge in commutative algebra.