# The variety of the chords to the rational normal cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Harris' Algebraic Geometry - a first course, and I am stuck at trying to figure out how the chords of a rational normal cubic curve form a projective variety. Could anyone point me in the right direction for understanding this?

Comment: Do you mean, considered as a subset of the Grassmannian?

Comment: @JakeLevinson I am just looking at a twisted cubic - an image of the map from $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$ given by $[X_0,X_1] \rightarrow [X_0^3,X_0^2X_1,X_0X_1^2,X_1^3]$. The chords of this curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are supposed to form a variety.

Comment: It is impossible for a beginner to understand  Lecture 1  of Harris's book and even more impossible to solve the exercises.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg what would you suggest to go before it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recomendations

Comment: That is excellent, I don't know how I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: [Another thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/reference-for-algebraic-geometry/46854#46854) ...[And yet another one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174435/algebraic-geometry-text-recommendation/174500#174500)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you very much. This is going to come in very handy in the following months.

Comment: My pleasure, baltazar: I am glad that the links were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily obvious immediately, but every point of $\mathbb{P}^3$ is on some (unique, in fact) chord of the twisted cubic. So it's not interesting to consider "points in $\mathbb{P}^3$ lying on chords to the twisted cubic". Rather, the point is to look in the Grassmannian,

$$G(2,4) = \{\text{lines } \ell \text{ in } \mathbb{P}^3\} = \{\text{2-dimensional vector subspaces of } \mathbb{C}^4\}.$$

This is, itself, a projective variety, with a standard embedding in $\mathbb{P}^5$ -- if you aren't familiar with it, you might be better off learning a bit more about it before doing this problem. You can probably find this info elsewhere in the textbook, or on the internet. I happen to have written a blog post or two about Grassmannians in general here: http://levjake.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/schubert-calculus-i-geometry-of-gkn/. But I can't promise it'll be accessible.

Anyway, you want to consider the subset of $G(2,4)$ consisting of those lines $\ell$ that are chords (or tangents) to the twisted cubic, and show that this is a closed (algebraic) subset of $G(2,4)$, hence also a projective variety.

This more or less boils down to the fact that the condition "$\ell$ is a chord to the twisted cubic" is a Zariski-closed condition, meaning you can express it in terms of certain algebraic equations that must be satisfied in $G(2,4)$.

Comment: For some reason this is one of the first examples in Harris' book, so I thought that I should be able to understand it almost immediately. I'll try reading your blog post. I now understand the problem better. Thank you.

Comment: Long live your interesting blog!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks!