# Can you recommend a good textbook for Algebraic geometry for a beginner?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to learn Algebraic geometry. My main focus will be on **Varieties**.

Can you recommend a good textbook for Algebraic geometry for a beginner?

Comment: Please see [Algebraic Geometry Text Recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174435/algebraic-geometry-text-recommendation).

Comment: I will suggest Fulton's Algebraic Curves. I found it easy to follow as a beginner. It's good one to establish basic ideas.